# ui-bootstrap 0.13 - How to use tooltip-html inside an ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

trying to switch from tooltip-html-unsafe to tooltip-html because the former one is deprecated in ui-bootstrap 0.13.0

in the example, the tooltip-html content is provided in the controller as

```
<a href="#" tooltip-html="htmlTooltip">Check me out!</a>

$scope.htmlTooltip = $sce.trustAsHtml('I\'ve been made <b>bold</b>!')
```

is there a proper solution for when the content is inside an ng-repeat?
simply switching to tooltip-html produces a $parse error

EDIT / SOLUTION:

Actually, i got around it by simply adding single quotes like so:

```
tooltip-html="'Line 1<br>Line <strong>2</strong>'"
```

I think when the html is more complicated, you need to use the answer by Shawn below

Comment: you should add your own answer for clarity

Answer (score 1):

Use the tooltip-template directive.

controller:

```
$scope.fruits=["Bananas","Apples","Oranges"]
```

html:

```
<div ng-repeat="fruit in fruits">
    <div tooltip-template="'myTooltipTemplate.html'">TOOLTIP</div>
</div>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="myTooltipTemplate.html">
     <b>Fruit</b> : {{fruit}}
</script>
```

link to plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/yUPl6hCACHKzvCBwrDUf?p=preview